# Connecting conduit to back of sub panel

Tags: electrical, wiring

I’m installing a sub panel in my shed, and I’m not quite sure the best way to secure the conduit to the panel. I’d like to run the conduit on the outside of the wall and connect into the rear of the panel with an LB through the T11.

Can I just run the LB directly into the back of the panel without a threaded end securing it? Adding a male adapter on the outside seems like it would make the LB stand out quite far from the wall.

Comment: What kind of conduit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming PVC conduit, use a male adapter **into** the LB, a metal LB with female threads in it, a metal close nipple, and a metal locknut in the panel.

Not sure if a (glue in) PVC box adapter into a metal box is allowed - it might be, but I've only ever seen those installed into PVC boxes. But I haven't seen everything. That would be another way to do it if it's allowed, and less expensive.

Answer (score 1):

### Use a "Rigid chase nipple"

[image]

It is designed to thread into the back of the LB and firmly nut down and trap the metal of the LB against the back of the subpanel, and assure firm contact.

If you have a non-threaded PVC LB, then take it back and get something threaded.

The only way I can thing to do this with smooth-wall (glued) PVC is to glue on a male screw thread, then have a normal conduit nut in the panel. Hmm, that might work if you can get a really low profile male screw thread.